# Designing JPA Entity object for onToMany mapping on Same Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

If we have a table say EMP_CONTACTTYPE which is as below

```
EMP  EMPNAME CONTACTTYPE CONTACT
1     W      1           EMAIL
2     X      1           EMAIL
3     Y      2           PHONE
4     Z      2           PHONE
```

If we want to display the details as

```
EMAIL    PHONE
W        Y
X        z
```

How should we design the entity object's as its mapping to the same table " EMP_CONTACTTYPE " .

I created two Entity Object one for Contact and one for Emp as below and have got a onetomany mapping on Contact Entity

Below is the Contact Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP_CONTACTTYPE")
public class CONTACT
{
private String CONTACT_TYPE;
private String CONTACT;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "EMP_CONTACTTYPE", joinColumns = { xxxxxx })    
private List<EMP> EMP;
}
```

and below is the EMP Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP_CONTACTTYPE")
public class EMP
{
private String EMPLOYEE_NAME;
private String EMPLOYEE_KEY;
}
```

The result expected is like for Contact Object Type (1 and Email) We need two objects of Employee (W and X). Am not sure whether join is the solution for this or am not clear how to add a join for this. Any suggestion in designing this scenario.

Comment: Imo, this does not appear to be a well designed database.  It is not as normalized as it can be and so I would say it lacks flexibility.  The EMP_CONTACTTYPE table contains data that is not wholly independent: an emoloyee may have more than one set of contact info, each of a different type.  A normalized design would split them apart and establish a relationship between the two tables.  Moreover, the CONTACT and CONTACTTYPE fields appear to be duplications of the same information, since the CONTACT field can be derived from the CONTACTTYPE field.  It should be omitted from the database.

Comment: @scottb Ya agreed .. Its a bad design . Splitting the table and defining the relation is the proper solution.. but I do have a similar requirement and the DB is already defined long back so will not be able to change the Database design. How to proceed in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your two Entity classes into a single Entity class or use two tables.

Preferably, however, you would split this into two tables and create an appropriate relationship between the two tables. The current schema design is not optimal.

Anyway, given you situation and based on your comment, since you have a single table that contains all of this data, you can extend the `EMP` class from the `CONTACT` class and create a discriminator column. Going with this approach you will find the following class annotations useful:

e.g.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "columnname", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "value")
```

You should research these annotations and choose the appropriate strategy, etc. This should get you on the right path.

If you use Discrimators with Hibernate, you also have the option to specify a *formula*
e.g.

```
<discriminator formula="case when CLASS_TYPE in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 0 else 1 end"     type="integer"/>
```

Comment: But database is already designed and if it cant be changed how to proceed . By Creating a single entity how to provide the relation between Employee and ContactType . It should be onetomany (for one Contactype many Employees)

Comment: I was trying to use the above said approach but I have a concern with Discriminator value . How to add the discriminator value on the entity there might be lot of values.. What I did was I created the discriminator column of contactType but we don know right there might be lot of values in that columns.

Comment: If there is a fixed set of discriminator values, you can create a class for each

Comment: These are not fixed set of values. As in the example above there may be lot of ContactType Values

Comment: In the case, there is nothing in JPA that will enable you to dynamically generate a discriminator value. Some JPA implementations to provide a mechanism outside the JPA spec to enable dynamic values. For example, with hibernate you can specify a 'formula' e.g. `<discriminator     formula="case when CLASS_TYPE in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 0 else 1 end"     type="integer"/>`

Comment: If there are fixed set of ContactType values, you can take the inheritance approach i mentioend above